# when i am creating a listing , i am getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

```
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select_tag(:location_id,options_for_select(@locations), :prompt=>"select your location")%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select_tag(:category_id,options_for_select(@categories), :prompt=>"select a category")%>
```

listing_controller.rb

```
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}

  @locations= Location.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
end


def edit
   @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
    @locations= Location.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
end


def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

  @listing.category_id = params[:category_id]
  @listing.location_id = params[:location_id]

  @listing.user_id = current_user.id


  respond_to do |format|
    if @listing.save
      format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems like you does not have any Category or Listing instances.

Comment: On wich do you get that error?

Comment: i have fix the error

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined method map for nil class means you're calling the method on something that's nil. Nil class does not have that method.

debug your code to find out what is causing the object to be nil class

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this error before assigning the value to select option tag if its nil or not by the below code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <% unless @locations.empty? %>
    <%= select_tag(:location_id,options_for_select(@locations), :prompt=>"select your location")%>
   <% end %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <% unless @categories.empty? %>
    <%= select_tag(:category_id,options_for_select(@categories), :prompt=>"select a category")%>
  <% end %>
```